# Problema Logout Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

Tengo un problema al hacer **"Logout"** en mi aplicación, cada vez que el usuario hace "logout", lo redirecciona a volver a pedir sus credenciales, pero si el usuario refresca la ventana (<kbd>F5</kbd>) vuelve a iniciar sesión, lo que busco es la manera de matar la sesión cada vez que el usuario le da **"Logout"**. Esta es la configuración que estoy usando:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/forgotpassword").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/validateusername").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/helpdesk").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/employee/fromusername").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()

            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .permitAll()
        .and().csrf().disable();

   }
```

Comment: Hola @Edgar. Por favor trata de mantener tu pregunta lo más concisa posible sobre el problema. Trata de evitar los textos como "Hola!", "Espero que alguien me ayude", "Gracias!" y similares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega esta parte:

`.and().logout()
.deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
.logoutUrl("/logout")`

No veo por ningún lado la configuración de logout en tu código.

Comment: Me funcionó perfectamente, justo lo que buscaba. Gracias